# Customizing a date field in a model form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Let me start out by saying this question is basic, and almost certainly has been answered elsewhere if I only could find exactly what I need.

I have users who will be entering dates in some screwy formats, which won't be recognized by the usual validation code for the DateField (for instance, 2014/4 which I will want to convert to 2014-4-01 internally). Do I need to mess with the code to clean, validate, or both for this, and if I redefine those functions do I need to explicitly call super?

My thought was that maybe I should give the model field and the form field different names, and somehow fill the model field with the form field data when I process the form... but the how of that is vague.

```
class Person(models.Model):
  (some other fields)
  date_of_arrival = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
  (some other fields)
  date_of_arrival = forms.DateField(required=False, help_text="Date of arrival in town")
  class Meta:
     model = Person     
     fields = (..., date_of_arrival, ...)
```

Comment: why don't u use datepicker(http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)? :)

Answer (score 0):

$date = date('Y-m-d',$urvalue);

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a [`_clean()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) in your form, where the name of the field is before the `_`, so in your example it would be `date_of_arrival_clean()`.

In this method, do all your validations. I would recommend the `dateutil` package, which provides [`parse` method](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) that is designed to take a string that could possibly be a date, and convert it to a date. Using this method you will not have to write the mundane logic, instead your entire method would be:

```
def date_of_arrival_clean(self):
    user_input = self.cleaned_data['date_of_arrival']
    try:
        d = parse(user_input)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        raise forms.ValidationError('{} is not a valid date'.format(user_input))
    return user_input
```

> My thought was that maybe I should give the model field and the form
>   field different names

You don't have to do this ... you can keep the same fields as in your model form and still implement the `_clean()` method as described above.

Keep in mind that if your form is a ModelForm, then django will also do database validation when try to validate the form.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for! I apologize for asking such a simple question, that helped a lot.